# How to set two different sizes for single textview in android

Tags: android

> In my android app i need to set two different sizes in single textview. i tried Spannable but not working correctly. what i tried was

```
String Amount = "Rs.109";                                     
Spannable Passspan = new SpannableString(Amount);
Passspan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.75f), 1, 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
txt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);   
txt.setText(Passspan);
```

> I want "Rs." as text size of 10 and rest of them as text size of 15. The total count of amount may vary to different sizes such as "Rs.109" , "Rs.1000" like that . guide me...

Comment: Why not using a combination of TextView and EditText? Or TextView and TextView.

Comment: @nabin: can u pls give a sample

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Thank you very much for your support guys...This helps me to get two different font size in single textview.

```
String Amount="Rs.109";
txt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15);
Spannable span = new SpannableString(Amount);
span.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.75f), 0, 3,       
Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
txt.setText(span);
```

Comment: Can you please explain what does this do? Or at least comment the code..

Comment: There is also `AbsoluteSizeSpan` if you want it fixed and not related to original text size

Answer (score 4):

You can try using the Html hack, but it is not a recommended solution.

```
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.format("<font size=\"10\">Rs.</font><font size=\"15\">%s</font>", amount)));
```

Where `amount` is the numerical value. Just as 50, 100, 1000, ...

The recommended approach is to use two `TextViews` inside a horizontal `LinearLayout`.

Comment: @sivanesan1 if it worked for you then accept it as your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use HTML inside a TextView:

```
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText)));
```

Comment: can u pls give a sample

Comment: txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font size="6">size1</font><font size="4">size2</font>"));

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:text="Rs." />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:hint="Enter money" />
```

You can use TextView for both as well.

Comment: I guess he means that the value is changed from the activity. I guess two `TextView`s would work fine too. No need for `EditText`.

Comment: @MiroMarkarian I asked it in comment in question about that. This is enough right? No need to consider HTML

Comment: Yap. This is the way I recommended in my answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

use below code hope it might help you happy coding

```
String text = "<body><font size=3>Rs</font><font size=2>109</font></body>";
Spanned spanned1 = Html.fromHtml(text);
tvYourTextViewObject.setText(spanned1);
```

Comment: I was faster in this one :) (Please, please look in the answers before posting. It is unfair for the other ones that have answered sooner.)

Comment: @MiroMarkarian  being frank i was also in posting the answer there might be 1 to 2 second difference between us i wasnt saw any answer below this code before posting mine one :)

Comment: There is a 5 minute difference buddy. And even when you are typing there is a big bar on the top that says `New answer posted`. If you click that it will show you the new answers.

Comment: yup there is 5 min difference but i wasnt seen any answers